# Concatenate passed parameter to string variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to pass 2 parameters to my stored procedure, one of which I wish to use as a part of a variable definition. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2018. My stored procedure will take a consignment number as a parameter and append it to the variable where the definition will appear similar to this:

- passed parameter = `@ConsignmentNo`
- variable `@TmpDictionary = 'tmp.' + @ConsignmentNo + '_Dictionary'`

So that I may have a generated table name such as

```
tmp.Cons1234_Dictionary
```

SQL is throwing an error

> Must declare the table variable "@TmpDictionary"

Please see my attempt here:

```
/****** Object:  ---------------   Script Date: 29/06/2022 16:17:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE InsertProcedureNameHere 
    @Source varchar (max), 
    @ConsignmentNo varchar(max)
AS
    DECLARE
        @sql varchar(MAX),
        @loop int,
        @max_loop int,
        @TmpDictionary nvarchar(max) = 'tmp.' + @ConsignmentNo + '_Dictionary',
        @TmpThesaurus nvarchar(max) = 'mail.' + @ConsignmentNo + '_Thesaurus'
        
--set @TmpLookup = 'tmp.' + @JobNumber + '_Mailing_Lookup'
--set @MailSelection = 'mail. + @JobNumber + '_Mailing_Selection'

    SELECT @loop = MIN(ID) FROM @TmpDictionary 
    WHERE [Source] = @Source

    SELECT @max_loop = MAX(ID) FROM @TmpDictionary 
    WHERE [Source] = @Source

    --print @loop print @max_loop
    WHILE @loop <= @max_loop 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
                      ---------                                                          
        FROM @TmpDictionary t
        WHERE ID = @loop
               
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = '
                                update t
                                -------------------
                                from @Thesaurus t
                                where 1=1
                                -------------------                          
            PRINT (@sql)
            -- EXEC (@sql)
        END
                        
        SET @loop = @loop +1
    END
```

Please accept the fact that anything with dashes is just a placeholder for parts of the query that I cannot share or are needed for the purpose of this question. In a nutshell, I need to be able to pass a variable to my stored procedure, and use it within a variable definition to be able to reference tables dynamically using dynamic queries.

I hope this question makes sense!

Comment: This just screams of being a poor design decision. And from what you posted using a loop for your inserts is about the slowest possible way to tackle this.

Comment: Every `EXEC` creates a new scope; no variables from the outer scope are visible there. If you redesign your structure so none of this dynamic hoopla is necessary but the data numbers are stored as columns instead all of this suffering disappears, and you'll also not need loops as a bonus.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - from what I know the looping is necessary for searching through any table by ID where each ID is used to generate an output. This is an example that I modified so the code is not completely my own.

Comment: Even if the dynamic sql is needed, which I suspect it isn't, the code here will fail. Not only is the variable out of scope in the EXEC statement you would have to create a string to execute which that code is not doing.

Comment: If you stick with the dynamic sql approach I would urge you to use the sysname datatype instead of varchar(max). You have to protect against sql injection, no reason to give them up to 2gb of string length to play with.

Comment: Creating *tables* that are tightly coupled to data which is what you appear to have is a well documented anti-pattern and is to be avoided, and in almost all cases can be a with proper normalised design. Search Amazon for book of same name, Author Bill Karwin (also a SO contributor)

Comment: @SeanLange - for the purpose of the stored procedure the dynamic sql is necessary so that the same proc. can be run for any consignment without the user changing anything other than the consignment number and achieve a consistent result

Comment: As this is built on a system that runs on stored procedures that use dynamic sql I am doing my best to improve the users experience and make their job easier by 'automating' parts of the process. In that respect I need to stick to that similar method. Is there no way I can pass a variable to the proc. and use it to determine the table name, even when there are multiple tables that contain that consignment number?

Comment: The joys of _optimistic programming_. You've written `select ... from @TmpDictionary ...` so the expectation is that `@TmpDictionary` is a _table_ variable (`declare @TmpDictionary as Table ( Id Int, AnswersToLifesQuestions Bit );`). Instead, you've created a string variable and set it to a value that _might_ be the name of a table in hopes that the database will contemplate the value, divine your intentions, and go off and do something you desire. How might it know? And looping over a count rather than using, if absolutely necessary, a `cursor`. And validating the table names. ...

Comment: Thanks all for your input, I will rethink my approach as it clearly requires more of an understanding. Even though I didn't get the answer I wanted I still got some valuable suggestions.